# How do I identify the file system of a drive in Mac OS?

Tags: mac-osx, filesystems

I have an external drive hooked up to my Mac, and I'm trying to determine things like, e.g., is this HFS or FAT, is it 32-bit or 64-bit, etc. It seems like there should be some trivial command that gives me this info, but I can't seem to find one. Ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`diskutil(8)`](https://ss64.com/osx/diskutil.html) with the `info` predicate will give you information about a disk or partition.

Comment: link is dead mate

Comment: `diskutil list` also shows all available drives and volumes with their type (file-system).

Comment: `diskutil info -all`

Answer (score 6):

Highlight the volume in finder (note, that it must be the root of the volume), and hit <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>. The info dialog that appears shows you the filesystem type against the `Format` label.

Answer (score 6):

Running `mount` in `Terminal.app` also works and has way less noise when compared to `diskutil info -all`.

Comment: it works, but output is a bit ugly though.

Comment: `mount | column -t` makes it less visually dense.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're wedded to doing it from the command line, use Disk Utility and it's "Info" button.

Answer (score 1):

The 'mount' will show the filesystem type.